# Recycle Button Click Event c#

Tags: c#, methods, buttonclick

I want to recycle a Button click Event method in different parts of my application, I would change the filter of the file and the variable where to save the path to file. How could I refactor my code to reuse the method? I'm working with C#

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Click on the button "Examinar" and open a file explorer window and select the .ipr file.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e">Routed event arguments called E.</param>
    private void Button_Click_Examinar(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog
        {
            Filter = "Text files (*.ipr)|*.ipr"
        };
        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            iprPath = openFileDialog.FileName;
        }

        fileUploadBox.Text = iprPath;
    }
```

I need to change iprPath and Filter file type. Thanks!

Comment: Move the filtering to a separate method, and call that method from any evenhandler-method.

Comment: Can you give me an example? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could move the logic to a separate method:

```
private void ChoseFile(string filter, TextBox textBoxToUpdate)
{
    string fileChosen = null;
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog
    {
        Filter = filter
    };
    if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        fileChosen = openFileDialog.FileName;
    }

    textBoxToUpdate.Text = fileChosen;
}
```

The method takes two arguments - a `string` with a filter for the `OpenFileDialog`, and a `TextBox` that will be updated once a file is chosen.

Suppose you have three buttons, with three corresponding textboxes, you could then use the method like this:

```
private void IprFileButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   ChoseFile("Text files (*.ipr)|*.ipr", tbIprFile);
}

private void TextFileButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ChoseFile("Text files (*.txt)|*.txt", tbTextFile);
}

private void ImageFileButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ChoseFile("Image Files|*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png;*.gif;*.tif", tbImageFile);
}
```

Comment: Hi!!! Thanks!!
Now I understand everything! Thank you so much!